# How to remove or clear a Tabbar image in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, tabbar

Currently, I am working in simple iPhone application, using Tabbar to create three option and set three images in each view controller, then I click second tabbar show the viewcontroller2 and navigate to another screen, at the time i want to clear or remove tabbar image from this screen, But I can't fix this, please help me.

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setAlpha:0.5];
```

Comment: In any event the tabbar image does not get removed unless you remove it urself... pls provide ur code for a see- thru ...

Comment: Is it possible to clear this?

Comment: You are responding to questions, but not really making it very clear what you want to accomplish. You have a tabbar showing with three tabs. You want to "remove tab bar image" but want to keep the tab bar showing (I think). So you want to keep showing the 3 tabs, but remove the icon that is showing in the second tab? It would help everyone if you can clarify what it is you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to solve it:

```
UITabBarItem *filterTab = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
[filterTab setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
```

You can also pass a `nil` value for the `setImage` property. Like: `[filterTab setImage:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

Do this at the point you want to hide the tab bar view.  (maybe in viewWillAppear in the other screen you navigate to from viewcontroller2.

```
[self.tabbarcontroller.tabbar setHidden:YES]
```

Comment: could you explain more what you are trying to do?  Do you want the whole tab bar to be hidden when that other view is being displayed, and reappear again when the user goes back? If so you need to 'unhide' it - possibly in the viewWillDissappear or in the viewWillAppear of the other view (using setHidden:NO)

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible if you do

```
presentModalViewController
```

on `UIWindow`

I think, this will solve your issue

Hope it helps you....